# Numbering series with "through" or "to"

Tags: prepositions

I would like to know if a construction that I've read few times is indeed correct. When referring to a number of items, is it correct to say "The item numbers ranged from 4 **through** 7"? Is it better to say ""The item numbers ranged from 4 **to** 7"?

Moreover, if both sentences were correct, any hint about their usage?

Comment: The first one is better since it unambiguously tells the reader that 4 and 7 are both included.

Comment: *to* = end not necessarily inclusive; *through* = both inclusive. Some writers avoid *to* in such contexts altogether to avoid ambiguity. HTH.

Comment: use "2 up to and including 9" or if it's really important, say "from 11 to 14 inclusive" and if it is life-critical you say "from 11 to 14 inclusive of the 11 and 14"

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally prefer the former, as the two commenter up there explained, however the dictionary has a clear definition and explanation for this which is suggesting that the later is the correct form. See the check-marked line from part *b*:

> ### [***range***<sup>2</sup>    (v.)](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/range_2)
>
> **1 include [intransitive always + adverb/preposition]**
>
>   #### a) to include a variety of different things or people in addition to those mentioned range:
>
>     **from something to something**
>     *The show had a massive audience, ranging from children to grandparents.*
>
>   #### b) if prices, levels, temperatures, etc. range from one amount to another, they include both those amounts and anything in between:
>
>     **range *from* something *to* something ✓**
>     *There were 120 students whose ages ranged from 10 to 18.*
>     **range between something and something**
>     *The population of these cities ranges between 3 and 5 million.*
>     **range in age/size/price etc**
>     *The shoes range in price from $25 to $100.*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe old-fashioned, but I would still consider *through* as AmE, but not BrE.

In the example given, since it is an integral quantity we are talking about, it is clear that both ends of the range are included.